# Hive server not starting

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

Iam new to the hadoop ecosystem.  Tried to access hive through jdbc. For that I have written the following code

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveConnection {
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";


public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
  try {

      Class.forName(driverName);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(1);
}
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from test.employees");
while (res.next()) {
  System.out.println(res.getString(1));
} }}
```

and started the hiveserver2 (hive version 0.12 & hadoop version 1.1.2)  through the terminal  and im getting the status as "Starting HiveServer" . When i tried executing the above code from eclipse im no getting any error and any results neither(Got the same when i executed the executable "hiveserver" ).

Can any one help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check the port 10000 if it has started the hiveserver ? 
lsof -i:10000 or netstat -ntulp | grep ':10000' should help you.

Hope you have used hive --service hiveserver -p 10000 for starting the server. (-p 10000) not required as it is the default port

Comment: @ArunAK i have started from $Hive_Home/bin > ./hiveserver2 but that gave me a reply starting hive server . I then used hive --service hiveserver as per ur suggestion.This worked. But can u please tell me where is this file hiveserver as i read that hiveserver2 is designed to support multiple clients at a time,where as the previous version hiveserver supports only one client at a time. can u plz explain...Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Following ways are most really reason for your problem.

1.Is the hive-jdbc-*.Jar having classpath like this "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" or "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"?

2.While connection,you need to pass the user name and password like this?

If you use hive server2 then you have to set the connection like below.

con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "", "");

Above ways are really helpful for you.

Thanks in advance.